# Ranger file manager: how to mark files from:to

Tags: linux, ranger

I'm using Ranger as my main file manager on ubuntu. What i'd like to do is select the first file in a list for marking/selection, then a last one and have all in between marked as well.

Similar to using a visual file manager you'd click the first file, hold down shift and then select the last one.

I've searched rc.conf and the web but can't find an answer to this. Help would be welcome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the key binding `V` (in upper case). Might be `vs` on some systems - you can examine the keybindings by pressing `?` then `k`. Here’s the description from the manual page:

> Starts the visual mode, which selects all files between the starting point and the cursor until you press ESC.  To unselect files in the same way, use "uV".

Comment: Thanks. had tried small letter v instead of V, this works great